# React Hooks - Reset the drop down

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am testing multiple select/option elements using React Hooks. I was able to populate the drop down menus from local list and also using axios API getter method. Finally, I created a reset button to reset these drop down values to it originals (like "select a state" and "select an author") but could not get that to work, I am not sure what is the best way to reset these values.

Instead of posting the code in here, I added a link to this sample project in here. Any tips/pointers are much appreciated.

[codesanbox project link](https://codesandbox.io/s/38o6zzmlkq)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import StateSelector from "./StateSelector";
import Footer from "./Footer";

const SelectTesting = () => {
const reqUrl = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=redux";

const initialStateValue = [{ id: 0, value: " --- Select A State --- " }];
const initialAuthorValue = [" --- Select an Author --- "];

const allowedState = [
  { id: 1, value: "Alabama" },
  { id: 2, value: "Georgia" },
  { id: 3, value: "Missisippi" }
];

const [authors, setAuthors] = useState(initialAuthorValue);
const [allStates, setAllSelected] = useState(initialStateValue);
const [stateSelected, setStateSelected] = useState(initialStateValue[0].value);

let authorComponent = null;

// useEffect to get states
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Inside effect");
  const stateValues = initialStateValue;
  allowedState.map(sel => {
    stateValues.push(sel);
    return setAllSelected(stateValues);
  });
}, []);

// useEffect to get Authors
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Inside effect 2");
  axios(reqUrl).then(result =>
    result.data.hits.map(res => {
      initialAuthorValue.push(res.author);
      return setAuthors(initialAuthorValue);
    })
  );
}, []);

authorComponent = (
  <select>
    {authors.map((author, index) => (
      <option key={index}>{author}</option>
    ))}
  </select>
);

const stateSelectionHandler = event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  console.log(allStates);
  const stateIndex = allStates.findIndex(state => state.value === value);
  console.log(event.target.value, allStates, "index:", stateIndex);
  setStateSelected(event.target.value);
};

const resetClickHandler = () => {
  console.log("reset was clicked");
  setStateSelected(initialStateValue[0].value);
};

console.log("Inside Index.js Main");

return (
  <div>
    <hr />
      <StateSelector
      selectedState={stateSelected}
      allStates={allStates}
      onStateSelection={stateSelectionHandler}
      />
    <hr />
    <label>Author:</label>
    {authorComponent}
   <hr />
   <Footer onResetClick={resetClickHandler} />
  </div>
);
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<SelectTesting />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is actually only value attribute in your select element `<select onChange={onStateSelection} value={props.selectedState}>`

However I dont think the `StateSelector` component needs to be stateful component. It is better to make it controlled/dumb component that only takes props from parent and let parent control its value and behavior.

https://codesandbox.io/s/j7zwxnn65w

Comment: Thank You!! Man, I was banging my head against the wall. Initially I had StateSelector component as stateless one, I changed this component a lot hopping to get this working. I was under the assumption if I could change one of the statefull variable it will re-render the dom in StateSelector... :)